# why does initialize a dictionary of lists using fromkeys affect how the list appends

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Creating a dict of lists using different methods

```
d1 = {'foo':[],'bar':[]}
d2 = dict.fromkeys(['foo','bar'],[])
```

yield two identical dicts.

```
print(d1==d2,d1,d2)

True {'foo': [], 'bar': []} {'foo': [], 'bar': []}
```

However, appending values to the lists

```
d1['foo'].append('a')
d2['foo'].append('a')

d1['foo'].append(2)
d2['foo'].append(2)
```

yields two different dicts. Why does the initialization method of a dict affect the list append behaviour?

```
print(d1==d2,d1,d2)

False {'foo': ['a', 2], 'bar': []} {'foo': ['a', 2], 'bar': ['a', 2]}
```

After fromkeys, python applies list append statements to all other keys too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `fromkeys`, what is happening is the dictionary is being created, and all its keys have the same object as their value.

What this means is that both `d2["foo"]` and `d2["bar"]` refer to the same object. It is the *same* object, not just an *identical* one. Therefore, modifying it via one key changes it across all other keys.

This is a lot more noticeable if you use a custom object:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = MyClass()
d = dict.fromkeys(["foo", "bar"], a)
```

Printing `d` yields the following output:

```
{'foo': <__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000000004699AC8>, 'bar': <__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000000004699AC8>}
```

Notice how the memory addresses are the same, because it is the same object.

In `d1` however, you do not assign the same object to both keys. Rather, you assign two separate *identical* ones (empty lists). Therefore modifying one does not change the other.